# Failed to add GPGKEY at http://cuda-repo/repos/GPGKEY to apt keys

Tags: apt, nvidia, repository, gnupg, cuda

I am trying to install JetPack-1.1.0 to my Ubuntu 14.04.2 x86_64 laptop. When the installation was at between %80 and %90 it warned me for `installation of cuda-toolkit-6-5 cuda-cross-armhf-6-5 failed. to continue the installation please be sure these packages are installed` then I downloaded `cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb` and try to start install cuda but when I try to add cuda-repo with `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb` failed with;

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Failed to add GPGKEY at http://cuda-repo/repos/GPGKEY to apt keys.
```

There is a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598383/insatlling-cuda-failed-to-add-gpgkey-at-http-cuda-repo-repos-gpgkey-to-apt-k) about this problem but there is no answer just method change to install cuda and I don't want to install that way. I want to solve this problem with your helps. I've tried [this.1](https://superuser.com/questions/854926/ubuntu-fails-to-install-cuda-toolkit), [this.2](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/569688/unable-to-install-cuda-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/) and just read [this.3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196704). Nothing changed with this.1 and this.2. `wget -q -O - http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/GPGKEY | apt-key add -` and `cat GPGKEY | apt-key add -` (tried both) outputs are OK but can't add cuda-repo again. I didn't find any vendor number about cuda-repo so I haven't tried it this.3 yet.

**EDIT:** I didn't find any solution before so I've re-installed ubuntu now I will again try to install with JetPack TK1. But edit reason is I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602386/cuda-6-5-failed-to-add-gpgkey-at-http-cuda-repo-repos-gpgkey-to-apt-keys) which is about the same problem and it also has accepted answer. Can the way solve the problem for everyone I don't know but maybe help someone.

Comment: I had the same problem. However, when I install CUDA 7.0 instead of 6.5, everything is fine. This is because repository problem, so you may manually configure repository (I don't know in details) again to install CUDA 6.5.

Comment: I installed it now with no error but I installed first the nvidia-331 driver not the latest driver.