# CUDA 6.5 Failed to add GPGKEY at http://cuda-repo/repos/GPGKEY to apt keys

Tags: software-installation, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 6.5 (not the most recent version CUDA 7.0) in order to work with some R package, which does only support CUDA 6.5 till now. My Ubuntu is:

```
deniz@deniz:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

According to [CUDA Documentation of Version 6.5](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) I am supposed to run

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

and this is what happens:

```
deniz@deniz:~$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 237074 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1404 (6.5-14) over (6.5-14) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1404 (6.5-14) ...
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Failed to add GPGKEY at http://cuda-repo/repos/GPGKEY to apt keys.
```

I am relatively new to Ubuntu,so I would really appreciate your help. I have looked at similar problems, but it did not help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using apt to force install the dependencies, and bypassing the security check, using the --allow-unauthenticated flag after you ran dpkg -i?

```
sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install -f
```

If this doesn't work, try moving the deb file to the apt archives then installing it using apt-get:

```
sudo mv cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install cuda-repo-ubuntu1404
```

You might have to try typing out the entire package name up to the .deb part for it to install, I'm not sure. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I tried your first approach but I ended up with the same initial problem. Then I tried your second suggestion which gave me the following: deniz@deniz:~$ sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install cuda-repo-ubuntu1404Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda-repo-ubuntu1404 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: That means that Ubuntu thinks it's already installed, so let's purge your system of that package, then retry my second option: sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda-repo-ubuntu1404

Comment: Try that, then move the .deb back to the archives and reinstall it again, being sure you use the --allow-unauthenticated flag. That should work. If not, lemme know when the output.

Comment: Also, are you just trying to install the nvidia graphic cards drivers? Because if so, you don't need Cuda, you'd install something different from a ppa. I had to do that just recently. That driver includes the Cuda libraries.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. Finally the problem was solved by turning off lightdm while installing. I found the solution from some other post here on askubuntu. (I will add it once I find the answer again)

Comment: Haha, no problem! That's funny, I never would've suspected a gpg letting error simply because lightdm was running. Yeah, I had to turn off lightdm to install my nvidia drivers too. But I'm glad to have been able to help some! And welcome to the ubuntu community I might add!

Answer (score 0):

For installing the cuda-6.5 libraries, I solved this issue by installing the 340.76 driver separatly, obtaining the installation run file from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.76/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.76.run&lang=us&type=geforcem), then install the cuda library run file I obtained from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-65).

When I installed the cuda toolkit library, I had to use the override flag as my compiler was newer:

```
sudo ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --override
```

I verified the driver installtion worked using `nvidia-smi` and that the cuda libraries installed correctly by compiling by running `make` within the `./NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/` directory then running `./deviceQuery`.

I will note that I still need to sort out permissions of the installed libraries as the installation process required root and did not set the permissions such that I can use them as a regular user.