# Problems Installing CUDA on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, nvidia, cuda

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I don't seem to be able to get cuda to install nicely.

I have tried using:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

This appears to work but I don't get a cuda-5.5 folder in
/usr/local

Should I still be expecting this folder?

I have also tried installing Cuda 6.5 which is what I had previously got working before needing a fresh install.

I tried this from the deb file

sudo dpkg -i cuda.....
but it fails trying to write the GPGKEY similar to:
[Insatlling CUDA : Failed to add GPGKEY at http://cuda-repo/repos/GPGKEY to apt keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598383/insatlling-cuda-failed-to-add-gpgkey-at-http-cuda-repo-repos-gpgkey-to-apt-k?lq=1)

I have also tried the 6.5 .run file which after installation of the 340 driver and reboot Ubuntu login fails to load.

I tried following the install instruction from Nvidia but get similar issues.

I have previously installed cuda (5.5 & 6.5) on ubuntu (12 & 14) successfully and have no idea what to try next...

Any help please?

Thanks

Iain